# how to i make div occur after each other not next to each other in html?

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following code in html

```
    <div class="cards-wrapper">

        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <img src="../images/placeholder.jpg" width="500">
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum
            </p>
            <img src="../images/placeholder.jpg" width="500">
        </div>

    </div>
```

as well as this css code to go along with it

```
.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 90vw;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1%;


    background-color: var(--colour-element-hover);
    border-radius: var(--bord-rad);

    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}


.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1%;


    background-color: var(--colour-element-background);
    border-radius: var(--bord-rad);

    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
```

my problem is when I view the page my card divs are being placed next to each other [like in the image provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJNd.png) what I want is for each card div to be placed one after the other vertically with the lighter purple going around all of them

I have tried a lot of things but I'm quite new to html and css so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If you're using flexbox you can specify the flex direction to be vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using flexbox, just add `flex-direction: column;` to the wrapper to make them stack vertically:

```css
.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* Stack with flex-direction */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: var(--colour-element-hover);
    border-radius: var(--bord-rad);
    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}


.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: var(--colour-element-background);
    border-radius: var(--bord-rad);
    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/500x500" width="500">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <img src="https://placehold.co/500x500" width="500">
    </div>
</div>
```